# Converting a TreeNodePath to a TreeNode

Tags: c#, winforms, path, treenode

Just thought id share this solution for anyone having this problem. I was working on trying to find a solution to this problem for several hours and since I frequent this website all the time to find solutions I thought id give back.

Comment: I appreciate you for posting your code to help others, but you posted in a wrong place. This is the place to ask questions, add your answer by clicking "Post your answer" button below. and only question in question section. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private TreeNode nodeFromPath(String path)//Converts a treenode path into a treenode
{
    TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();

    char[] delimiters = {'\\'};

    string[] roots = path.Split(delimiters);
    List<int> nodeIndeces = new List<int>();

    for(int j = 0; j < roots.Length ;j++)
    {
        nodeIndeces.Add(selectedNode.Index);
        selectedNode = selectedNode.Parent;
    }
    nodeIndeces.Reverse();
    tn = treeView1.Nodes[0];

    for (int i = 1; roots.Length > i; i++)
    {
        tn = tn.Nodes[nodeIndeces[i]];
    }

    return tn;

}//end nodeFromPath
```